# Where the div or ul CSS classes are defined

Tags: css, html

I would like to understand where the `div` or `ul` CSS classes are defined.
For example I can see in my application code like this:

```
<ul class="carousel jcarousel-skin">
```

But when I search in all my application I can not able to  find the declaration of class `carousel jcarousel-skin`

Can you help?

Comment: @KiranPurbey When you edited, you broke the code formatting by removing those four spaces in front of the code. I put back the four spaces, but please be more careful about that in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it is not a single declaration.

It is two classes applied (*`carousel` and `jcarousel-skin`*). Each could be anywhere in your css files, and they might not even exist as they might be used just for easy targeting from javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You can use css style from external file by linking it to your html page or by html attribute "style" inside the html element.

Answer (score 0):

There could be also a possibility that the CSS classes that you are looking for are referenced from remote location as CDN. You should look through css files which are linked as below:

`<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet">`